# List of List String in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, javafx, arraylist

I have a problem with the implementation of List>, it gives me always the last element duplicated. Here is a bunch of my code :

Here is the declaration of my list and the list of lists.

```
public List<List<String>> survs = new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> surveillance = new ArrayList<>();
public int k=0;
```

Here i add to the list some strings.

```
  public void handleAddSURVClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    survName = name.getText();
    max = maxp.getText();
    min = minp.getText();
    surveillance.add(survName);
    surveillance.add(monitoredObject);
    surveillance.add(monitoredProperty);
    surveillance.add(max);
    surveillance.add(min);
    // Add surveillance to the vector
    survs.add(k, surveillance);k++;
    //Surv initialisation
    survName = ""; name.clear();
    max = ""; maxp.clear();
    min = ""; minp.clear();
    monitoredObject = "";
    monitoredProperty = "";

}
```

then simply i add the list to the list of lists and i specify an index in which i wanna store my list and i print the list of lists ( survs )

```
    survs.add(k, surveillance);k++;
    System.out.println(survs);
```

Unfortunately, it gives me this result after submitting two lists, it gives just the last one redundant:

```
    [[yas, ProductSurrounding, charge, 667, 524, stack, ProductSurrounding, charge, 8787, 6422], [yas, ProductSurrounding, charge, 667, 524, stack, ProductSurrounding, charge, 8787, 6422]]
```

if i do surveillance.clear(), the results will be two empty lists [[],[]]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is that all code involved?

Comment: "it gives me this result after submitting two lists" ??? - show us the code.

Comment: use `set` instead of `add` on arraylist

Comment: Without minimal code required to reproduce the bug its not possible to help. I need to see at least the information whether you are clearing or creating a new instance of the list `surveillance` for each `k`

Comment: @HemantPatel `add` is a correct method, the OP never wrote he wanted to replace an element by another one. And with set, you will more likely encounter an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: why don't you create a class named Surveillance and create object of that class. Your code will be easier to read and maintance.

Comment: Code edited :))

Comment: See my answer below it will solve your problem

Comment: You use only 1 instance of the survaillance entity, adding it multiple times to the survs list. What you need to do is instantiate a new list for new surveillance data. Moving the line declaring and initiating surveillance to the start of `handleAddSURVClick` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new instance of `surveillance` after each time you add it to the `survs`.But crate `survs` this instance only once.
Do like this :

```
    public void handleAddSURVClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        survName = name.getText();
        max = maxp.getText();
        min = minp.getText();
        surveillance=new ArrayList<>(); 
        surveillance.add(survName);
        surveillance.add(monitoredObject);
        surveillance.add(monitoredProperty);
        surveillance.add(max);
        surveillance.add(min);
        // Add surveillance to the vector
        survs.add(k, surveillance);k++;
        //Surv initialisation
        survName = ""; name.clear();
        max = ""; maxp.clear();
        min = ""; minp.clear();
        monitoredObject = "";
        monitoredProperty = "";

    }
```

And if you do `surveillance.clear()` then you are clearing the value in the reference of `surveillance` in your `survs`.So at the end all becomes empty.

Comment: Also try to get rid of that `k` thing.Just use add.